# Why this XBL example is not working?

Tags: css, xml, xul, xbl

This example is from [this Mozilla's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial:Adding_Methods_to_XBL-defined_Elements).

**main.xul**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="main.css" type="text/css"?>

<window xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <box id="num" class="labeledbutton" title="Number of Things:" value="52"/>

    <button label="Show" oncommand="document.getElementById('num').showTitle(true)"/>
    <button label="Hide" oncommand="document.getElementById('num').showTitle(false)"/>
</window>
```

**main.css**

```
box.okcancelbuttons {
    -moz-binding: url('main.xml#labeledbutton');
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<binding id="labeledbutton">
  <content>
    <xul:label xbl:inherits="value=title"/>
    <xul:label xbl:inherits="value"/>
  </content>
  <implementation>
    <method name="showTitle">
      <parameter name="state"/>
      <body>
        if (state) document.getAnonymousNodes(this)[0].
          setAttribute("style","visibility: visible");
        else document.getAnonymousNodes(this)[0].
          setAttribute("style","visibility: collapse");
      </body>
    </method>
  </implementation>
</binding>
```

Why it is not showing the box when I click the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems :

First of all in main.css you define a class `okcancelbuttons` yet in main.xul you refer to a `labeledbutton` class. The class can be called the same as the binding.

Secondly main.xml is just not valid xml (simplest way to validate is to load it up in firefox and it'll spit out errors).
It needs `xmlns` attributes for each namespaces you use. In this case the "main" namespace, xbl and xul. They should be defined in the missing `<bindings>` element around the `<binding>` element.

It'll end up like this :

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
          xmlns:xbl="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
          xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
 <binding id="labeledbutton">
  <content>
    <xul:label xbl:inherits="value=title"/>
    <xul:label xbl:inherits="value"/>
  </content>
  <implementation>
    <method name="showTitle">
      <parameter name="state"/>
      <body>
        if (state) document.getAnonymousNodes(this)[0].
          setAttribute("style","visibility: visible");
        else document.getAnonymousNodes(this)[0].
          setAttribute("style","visibility: collapse");
      </body>
    </method>
  </implementation>
 </binding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Just try it out**

**XUL(main.xul)**

```
<box id="num" class="labeledbutton" title="Number of Things:" value="52"/>

<button label="Show" oncommand="document.getElementById('num').showTitle(true)"/>
<button label="Hide" oncommand="document.getElementById('num').showTitle(false)"/>
```

**CSS(main.css)**

```
box.okcancelbuttons {
    -moz-binding: url('main.xbl#labeledbutton');
}
```

**XBL(main.xbl)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
          xmlns:xbl="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
          xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
 <binding id="labeledbutton">
  <content>
    <xul:label xbl:inherits="value=title"/>
    <xul:label xbl:inherits="value"/>
  </content>
  <implementation>
    <method name="showTitle">
      <parameter name="state"/>
      <body>
        if (state) document.getAnonymousNodes(this)[0].
          setAttribute("style","visibility: visible");
        else document.getAnonymousNodes(this)[0].
          setAttribute("style","visibility: collapse");
      </body>
    </method>
  </implementation>
 </binding>
</bindings>
```